# got stuck programming https proxy - what to do next?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I'm currently making a proxy which sits between the browser and the web. Everything works except https. I'm having troubles understanding some passages of it and haven't found many resources on the web. And so I'm stuck.

The code I'm using is:

```
conn, addr = server.accept()
request = conn.recv(9999) #get a CONNECT request
conn.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 Connection estabilished\n\n')
enc_req = conn.recv(9999) #this gets an encrypted request
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #plaintext client 
client.connect((host, 443)) #connect to chosen host 
client.send(enc_req)
resp1 = client.recv(9999) #this gets something unreadable (encrypted?)
#could it be the certificate?

#now what?
```

Is the resp1 I'm getting the certificate? And what do I need to do after that? (Or, which is the same, what does usually happens next with https?)

P.S. I know the question is somewhat generic, but please don't judge me too harshly. I've tried researching on the web but all I keep finding is the encryption method used for ssl. I really don't know how to proceed.

Comment: A HTTPS (SSL) connection is encrypted end-to-end, all a proxy can do is pass the data between the client and the server, nothing else.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm not sure how though.

Comment: @Martijn - SSL/TLS does not provide end-to-end encryption (though we often wish it so). [Trustwave](http://lwn.net/Articles/480279/) demonstrated how that promise was not delivered. There's an entire class of proxies used to break the expectations, and they bring their own set of problems such that an organization's attack surface often increases. See [SSL/TLS Interception Proxies and Transitive Trust](http://www.secureworks.com/cyber-threat-intelligence/threats/transitive-trust/).

Comment: @jww, that issue is mainly due to bad CA management. SSL/TLS, when configured properly, does provide end-to-end encryption. A CA that has its cert into mainstream OS/browsers should never do that, but a company could very well have its own CA that does just that.

Comment: @Bruno - SSL/TLS is end-to-end in theory, not in practice. In theory, we should achieve end-to-end security with opportunistic encryption (ADH or self-signed certificates). But we can't discard threats and vulnerabilities to suit our definitions :)

Comment: @jww You can have control over which certificates you want to trust (or not) with SSL/TLS, even in practice. TLS is end-to-end in practice, but you may indeed need to put some effort into what's beyond the scope of the protocol (trust management). The reality indeed is that it's complex for most users, and no one really looks into the list of CA certs in their browsers. However imperfect the PKI model is, it's still the most practical unfortunately (and some of its problems can be addresses with the likes of Convergence). I've looked at alternative WoT models, which turn out to be far harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this code (and it's mainly pseudo code), but this should give you an idea of what you need to do.

```
conn, addr = server.accept()
request = conn.recv(9999) #get a CONNECT request
# Here, parse the CONNECT string and get the host and port (not sure if you were doing that already.

# Then, try to connect *before* you tell the client the connection was established (in case it fails)
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) #plaintext client 
client.connect((host, 443)) #connect to chosen host 

conn.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 Connection estabilished\n\n')

# Then loop until the connections are closed.
while True:
    # Read from the client, send the data to the server.
    enc_req = conn.recv(9999) #this gets an encrypted request
    client.send(enc_req)

    # Read from the server, send the data to the client.
    resp1 = client.recv(9999) #this gets something unreadable (encrypted?)
    #could it be the certificate?
    #now what?
    # The first time it's certainly the Client Hello message, not encrypted, but in a binary format indeed.
    # Just send everything you've just read to the server.
    conn.send(resp1)
```

This is just a quick overview of the idea of the loop you need to write. In reality, you may be able to process both in parallel. You'd also want to be a bit more careful when closing the connection (allowing it to happen in any order while still relaying the last data sent by either party).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've hacked a bit on this and it works! And my code was mainly pseudo-code too ;)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, a proxy handling encrypted end-to-end traffic can only pass it on.

Here is a fully working proxy written using [circuits](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/circuits) that has been fully tested with passing and proxying SSH traffic so it should work equally as well as a pass-through TCP proxy even if SSL is involved:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from uuid import uuid4 as uuid

from circuits import Component
from circuits.net.events import close, connect, write
from circuits.net.sockets import TCPClient, TCPServer


class Client(Component):

    channel = "client"

    def init(self, sock, host, port, channel=channel):
        self.sock = sock
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        TCPClient(channel=self.channel).register(self)

    def ready(self, *args):
        self.fire(connect(self.host, self.port))

    def disconnect(self, *args):
        self.fire(close(self.sock), self.parent.channel)

    def read(self, data):
        self.fire(write(self.sock, data), self.parent.channel)


class Proxy(Component):

    channel = "server"

    def init(self, bind, host, port):
        self.bind = bind
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

        self.clients = dict()

        TCPServer(self.bind).register(self)

    def connect(self, sock, host, port):
        channel = uuid()

        client = Client(
            sock, self.host, self.port, channel=channel
        ).register(self)

        self.clients[sock] = client

    def disconnect(self, sock):
        client = self.clients.get(sock)
        if client is not None:
            client.unregister()
            del self.clients[sock]

    def read(self, sock, data):
        client = self.clients[sock]
        self.fire(write(data), client.channel)


app = Proxy(("0.0.0.0", 3333), "127.0.0.1", 22)

from circuits import Debugger
Debugger().register(app)

app.run()
```

Comment: A point I'm trying to illustrate in this answer is to use a suitable framework for this kind of problem. I would just ea easily advocate [Twisted](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twisted) which also has similar examples ready to go.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to solve it at a lower level for educational purposes, I don't have any pressure to get the job done quickly.

Comment: That's totally fine but eventually you will want to use something like AsyncIO, Twisted, circuits or Tornado.