# Coding multiple certificates with same self-signed CA?

Tags: firefox, ssl, proxy, openssl, self-signed

I'm writing an interception proxy to monitor the requests sent from my browser. With https, what I'm doing is: 
 when the browser makes a CONNECT request, the proxy connects to that host and gets its certificate. 
Then, the subject and subjectAltName of this certificate are used to generate a new certificate on the fly, which is presented to the browser to estabilish a SSL connection with the proxy.

All of these new certificates have as issuer a root self-signed certificate. 
The root certificate has already been imported as trusted in Firefox.

Yet, I still get an Untrusted connection warning when I try to connect and the following details:

```
www.google.com uses an invalid security certificate. 
The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is not trusted. 
(Error code: sec_error_untrusted_issuer)
```

The browser I'm using is Firefox 28.0. I haven't quite understood why the connection results untrusted, seeing as I have installed the root certificate. Right now I'd have to add an exception for each website I visit, which is frankly very annoying and slows down everything.

I'm using pyOpenSSL to make certificates.
The code I used to make the root certificate is:

```
    from OpenSSL import crypto
    CERT_FILE = 'myapp.pem'
    KEY_FILE = 'myapp.key'
    k = crypto.PKey()
    k.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 1024)

    cert = crypto.X509()
    cert.get_subject().O = "Myapp"
    cert.get_subject().OU = 'MyApp Root CA'
    cert.get_subject().CN = 'MyApp Root CA'
    cert.set_serial_number(888)
    cert.gmtime_adj_notBefore(0)
    cert.gmtime_adj_notAfter(10*365*24*60*60)
    cert.set_issuer(cert.get_subject())
    cert.set_pubkey(k)
    cert.sign(k, 'sha1')

    with open(CERT_FILE, "wt") as cf: cf.write(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))
    with open(KEY_FILE, "wt") as kf: kf.write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, k))
```

Then, I use similar code to generate domain-specific certificates. Right now I'm working with an example using google only, although I'll be using some caching system as soon as I solve this.

```
root_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, 'myapp.pem') 
root_key = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, 'myapp.key') 
root_issuer = root_cert.get_issuer()

def make_example_cert(pem_data):
    if os.path.exists('google.pem'): return #ugly hack to avoid remaking file
    #load the certificate received from google 
    old_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, pem_data) 
    #generate new key and certificate
    pkey = crypto.PKey()
    pkey.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 1024)
    new_cert = crypto.X509()
    new_cert.gmtime_adj_notBefore(0)
    new_cert.gmtime_adj_notAfter(10*365*24*60*60)
    #set same subject of old cert
    new_cert.set_subject(old_cert.get_subject())
    #look for and set SNA of old cert
    for i in range(old_cert.get_extension_count()):
            ext = old_cert.get_extension(i)
            if ext.get_short_name() == 'subjectAltName':
                new_cert.add_extensions([ext])
    #set root certificate as issuer
    new_cert.set_issuer(root_issuer)
    new_cert.set_pubkey(pkey)
    new_cert.sign(root_key, 'sha1')
    certfile = 'google.pem'
    keyfile = 'google.key'
    with open(certfile, "wt") as cf:
        cf.write(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, new_cert))
    with open(keyfile, "wt") as kf:
        kf.write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, pkey))
    #append root certificate to chain
    with open(certfile, "at") as cf2:
        cf2.write(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, root_cert))

    return certfile, keyfile
```

I don't seem to find major bugs here, and when I view the certificate created it correctly has my own certificate root as issuer. Still, the browser says it's untrusted. It works if I add it as an exception, but for some websites I don't even have that option and the only thing I can do is viewing the details and clicking "Get me out of here".

Could the problem be in the code? Or is it a matter of configuring the browser?

Comment: I asked here because it may as well be a mistake in the logic of the program, or it could be fixed working on the code rather than the browser.

Comment: @jww has a point, it's really borderline on-topic as it stands. It could be on topic, in the context of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24325367/372643), but there would need to be more details on your actual code. So far, it still looks like a "fix my bug" type of question with little to go on. Your edit to this question also makes it awkward for existing answers (since it no longer really matches), and it's overall unlikely to be of interest to anyone else in the future. Please improve your question...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions. I'll edit that as soon as I'm on a proper pc.

Comment: `cert.get_subject().CN = 'MyApp Root CA'...` - +1 for using a friendly name in the `CN`, and placing the DNS names in the `SAN`.

Comment: "...Yet, I still get an Untrusted connection warning when I try to connect..." - we need to see the output of `openssl s_client -tls1 -connect google.com:443 -servername google.com`. Be sure to use DNS tricks so google.com resolves to your proxy. You might even be able to use SNI to trick/avoid DNS: `openssl s_client -tls1 -connect <proxy>:<port> -servername google.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your CA cert has been imported into Firefox as a trusted CA, it should work.

"*The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.*" and "*The certificate is only valid for MyApp CA Root*" indicate that you're visibly not serving the server certificates you think you are.

Either it's a simply bug in your code whereby you're sending the wrong certificate, or perhaps you might be sending the chain in the wrong order: CA cert first, whereas the End-Entity Certificate should be first (followed by its CAs, in signing order).

Comment: I've found a bug in the code (I was connecting using the root certificate instead of the other generated certificates). I still get an error though. I've edited the question with the new one.

Comment: You probably didn't import that CA certificate into your browser correctly, or you didn't generate your certificates with the correct issuer.

Comment: Did you check the time validity? It's possible that your proxy and your clients aren't set with exactly the same time. I'd adjust the notBefore with a negative value, for example.

Comment: Checked that. Still got the error. Seeing as I'm now going to format the pc I'll see if it's something to do with the browser.

Comment: Try to increase the key size to 2048 perhaps: https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:MD5and1024